# Return less data if user is not authorized

Tags: c#, .net, service, authorization

I have this method in a Controller:

```csharp
[Route("api/AppSearch/Search")]
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public async Task<ResponseEntity<AppSearchResponse>> Search([FromBody] AppSearchRequest request, string type = "")
{
    IEnumerable<AppSearchResponse> data = await SearchServiceV2.Search(request.SearchCriteria, request.AppKeyColumn, request.Filters, request.MaxResults, type);
    if (data == null)
    {
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(string.Format("Unknown type ", type)),
            ReasonPhrase = "Unknown type"
        };
        throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
    }
    return this.AssembleSuccessResponse<AppSearchResponse>(data);
}
```

I want to return different data based on if the user is authorized or not. If the user is authorized, I want it to return AppSearchResponse and if not, a class with 3 members of AppSearchResponse.

My initial though is create AppSearchResponseBase that has those 3 fields and then have AppSearchResponse extend it. Then, check if the user is authorized inside the Controller method and serialize the `data` variable to either the AppSearchResponseBase or AppSearchResponse

e.g.

```csharp
if(authorized){
return this.AssembleSuccessResponse<AppSearchResponse>(data)
} else {
return this.AssembleSuccessResponse<AppSearchResponseBase>(data)
}
```

Am I better off just creating a new resource like `api/AppSearch/SearchUnauthorized/` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like have a single class of `AppSearchResponse` that has info like:

```
public AppSearchResponse{
    public string Username {get;set;}
    public DateTime Joined {get;set;}
    // etc
    public ExtendedData ExtendedData {get;set;}
}
```

And then only populate `ExtendedData` (which would contain the "secured" fields) if the user has the appropriate access. On the client side, `ExtendedData` would be `null`  if the client doesn't provide the appropriate credentials or whatever.

Comment: But then I have to change the UI to support the new serialized class (i.e. extendedData)

Comment: Do you currently have 2 views (one each for the complete and incomplete data), or one view that you alter based on the return type? Either way, you would be set up to handle this. In the former, alter the 'incomplete' view to not display the extra property; in the latter, handle it in the existing conditional.

Comment: I have one view for the complete data and there is no view for the incomplete as the data will be available only through API calls.

Comment: I was thinking there is a more obvious way of returning different data based on the roles. I might just stick to checking the role inside the controller method and do an IF-ELSE